# How numbers are summed in python?

Tags: python, sum

I am adding two numbers in python.

```
A = 29.000988000000003
B = 10
```

in python `A+B` gives `39.00098800000001.`

Can someone explain me what exactly is going on? According to me the last digit should be 3 not 1. Even with `B = 10.0` also gives same results..

Basically I want to know what is the machine accuracy of python and how I can avoid such incidents?

Comment: only the sums of powers of 2 can be accurately represented as floats.  what you see is normal

Comment: @wim Thanks for a quick reply. can you tell me how i can avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend reading this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

If you want to avoid such problems, please look at decimal python module:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

For example:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 17
>>> a = Decimal('29.000988000000003')
>>> b = Decimal('10')
>>> a + b
Decimal('39.000988000000003')
```

Answer (score 0):

quote from the doc:

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as
>   binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal
>   floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary
>   floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html